# Problem with ordering search in firestore with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble getting the proper order from a firestore query in swift.

```
func firestoreSearch() {

  let db = Firestore.firestore()

  myObjects.forEach( {j in
    print(j.id)
    db.collection("users").whereField("objectID", isEqualTo: j.id).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
      if let err = err {
        print("Error getting search results: \(err)")
      } else {

        for i in querySnapshot!.documents {

          print("\(i.documentID)")

          let id = i.documentID
          let title = i.get("title") as! String
          let price = i.get("price") as! String
          let imageURL = i.get("imageURL") as! String
          let phoneNumber = i.get("phoneNumber") as! String
          let classUsed = i.get("classUsed") as! String
          let uid = i.get("uid") as! String
          let condition = i.get("condition") as! String
          let location = i.get("location") as! String
          let author = i.get("author") as! String
          let description = i.get("description") as! String
          let date = i.get("date") as! String


          self.searchResults.append(datatype1(id: id, title: title, price: price, imageURL: imageURL, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, classUsed: classUsed, uid: uid, condition: condition, location: location, author: author, description: description, date: date))
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

In the above code, the terminal outputs the following:

```
ZT5wne5djpZB5okgo1J0

PDE6eftBQs5ZKnBVGyBF

fQYGzEDIJUS6mgL3oKCz

0p8Rh7dgniN5V9tDdVzG

PDE6eftBQs5ZKnBVGyBF

ZT5wne5djpZB5okgo1J0

0p8Rh7dgniN5V9tDdVzG

fQYGzEDIJUS6mgL3oKCz
```

There are 4 documents in the collection. Why are the last 4 printed document IDs not in the same order as the first 4. I am using Algolia to sort the results, and then passing them to this function, so I need them to stay in the same order.

Comment: Firebase is async code, which basically means it executes as fast as possible and not necessarily waiting for each loop to return before executing the next. Here, you are making 4 calls to Firebase and for whatever reason, certain ones are returning faster than others. This is supposed to be a positive thing because you are getting results as fast as possible.

Comment: @purebreadd Thanks for your reply what you said makes sense to me. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could maintain the order in this case, or am I approaching this problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `forEach` loop prints the document IDs in the first 4 lines in the order that they appear in the `myObject` array (it's not clear from your question how that order is set), and the last 4 lines are printed by your query completion closure. You are actually making 4 separate queries, and each query is a separate async request, so there's no guarantee that the order will be the same.

What you might want to do is make a query that returns all the documents you want in a single request:

```
func firestoreSearch() {

  let db = Firestore.firestore()

  let ids = myObjects.map { $0.id }

  db.collection("users")
    .whereField("objectID", in: ids)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

       for i in querySnapshot!.documents {
          print("\(i.documentID)")
          //...
       } 
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Firestore, so this is just from their documentation of [`whereField(_:in:)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#wherefield_:in:).

I'm not sure these would be in the order of IDs being specified (likely not), so you'd need to use another sorting parameter, or map to the sorting in the `myObjects` array.

Comment: Thanks for your help. By using your suggestion and using order(by:) I was able to get the desired result. Unfortunately, whereField only accepts 10 values, but I should be able to make it work if I paginate the document ids.